# EF stored proc getting called twice

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that takes about 2 seconds to run and return a table from sql server management studio. It returns about 8k records. When I run from EF it takes about 1 min to run and return. I turn on debugging with the below line op code and I notice it runs the proc twice. Both in about 30 seconds. Does anyone have any ideas as to why EF is doing this? Do I have control over this? Is there a way to speed this up? How many records get returned seems to dictate if it's called once or twice. I have an example that returns 2k records and it only runs the proc once. I have some that return 8k+ and it runs it twice. Never seems to run it more than twice that I can see.

```
dbContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);


var data = dbContext.GetData(param1, param2);

Opened connection at 6/27/2014 9:33:36 AM -05:00

[dbo].[GetData]


-- param1: 'Test' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

-- param2: 'Test2' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

-- Executing at 6/27/2014 9:33:36 AM -05:00

-- Completed in 30309 ms with result: SqlDataReader



[dbo].[GetData]


-- param1: 'Test' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

-- param2: 'Test2' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)

-- Executing at 6/27/2014 9:34:07 AM -05:00

-- Completed in 30753 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Comment: Would be helpful to show some code and the log output.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't show it originally because it's 1 line of code to call the proc and text that just shows it's running it twice like my description says. It's not an error or anything, it's just something I'm wondering why and do we have control over it doing this.

Comment: If you want to see what is going on, recommend you use the Sql Profiler. If you are running over a slow connection, SQL could take 1 second, but result fetching could take 30 seconds

Comment: Is `GetData` a method you implemented yourself that calls `SqlQuery` internally, or a mapped Function Import generated by EF? I'm asking since I'm thinking it could be caused by the result set being enumerated twice, but if you use Function Import EF should not allow that.

Comment: GetData is imported via EF. I don't do anything manually.